# Indexing a pandas.Panel counterintuitive or a bug?

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some trouble understanding the indexing of a pandas.Panel (3D data structure). In the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/indexing.html) it is stated that the indexing works as:

> Getting values from an object with multi-axes selection uses the following notation (using .loc as an example, but applies to .iloc and .ix as well). Any of the axes accessors may be the null slice :. Axes left out of the specification are assumed to be :. (e.g. p.loc['a'] is equiv to p.loc['a', :, :])
>
> p.loc[item_indexer,major_indexer,minor_indexer]

Now i would assume that the order of the remaining indices do not change when a DataFrame is extracted, but:

```
from pandas import Panel
from numpy import arange
p = Panel(arange(24).reshape(2,3,4))
p.shape
Out[4]: (2, 3, 4)
p.iloc[0].shape # original order
Out[5]: (3, 4)
p.iloc[:,0].shape # transposed
Out[6]: (4, 2)
p.iloc[:,:,0].shape # transposed
Out[7]: (3, 2)
p.iloc[:,0,:].shape # transpose (same as [6])
Out[8]: (4, 2)
p.iloc[1:,0,:].shape # Slicing item_indexer, then transpose
Out[9]: (4, 1)
p.iloc[1:,0].shape # Expected to get the same as [9], but slicing minor_indexer instead????
Out[10]: (3, 2)
```

Any ideas why the DataFrame is transposed when indexing the major_index or minor_index, but not the item_index? And why is the last example different from the one before?

[Link to github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8906)

Comment: I guess nobody knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently there has been some discussion in the [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8906). It seems that pandas is not very well geared towards N-dimensional data (N >= 3). There is an alternative module [xray](https://github.com/xray/xray), which is like pandas but for ND data. Otherwise, you can use plain pandas (2D) DataFrames with MultiIndex to simulate ND data.